# order of selected rows/lines in QTableView's selectedItems

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, clipboard, qtableview

I am using a QTableWidget and want to copy some cells to clipboard. It seems the QTableWidget only supports the selectedItems method.
For some reason I get the output as first column and then second column. Not: first row and then second row. This makes it somehow difficult to seperate the cols/rows. Do you know what went wrong? Thanks!

```
  QList<QTableWidgetItem *> selectedCells(TableView->selectedItems());
  QTableWidgetItem * item;

  mCopyByteArray.clear();

  foreach(item, selectedCells)
  {
    mCopyByteArray.append(item->text());
    mCopyByteArray.append("\r\n");
  }
```

When building it up:

```
  TableView = new QTableWidget(); /* I know that name somehow is wrong ;) */
  TableView->setColumnCount(2);

  QStringList HHeaderList;
  HHeaderList << "Computer name" << "ServiceTag";
  TableView->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HHeaderList);
  TableView->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
  TableView->setEditTriggers(QTableWidget::NoEditTriggers);
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: So it goes through selectedCells like this? (row 0, column 0) then (row 1, column 0) and so on? But you want it to go (row 0, column 0) then (row 0, column 1)?

Comment: That's right! I think this should be the normal way.

Comment: I wrote a little algorithm to go through the QList selectedCells in the order you would like to have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QTableWidget::selectedRanges()` instead. Small Example:

```
#include <QList>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QTableWidgetSelectionRange>

/...

// you can have more than one selected areas in the table. So you can have more then one
// selected ranges
QList <QTableWidgetSelectionRange*> selectRanges(TableView->selectedRanges());

for (int i =0; i != selectRanges.size(); ++i) {
  QTableWidgetSelectionRange range = selectRanges.at(i);
  int top = range.topRow();
  int bottom = range.bottomRow();
  for (int i = top; i <= bottom; ++i) {
    QTableWidgetItem *item1 = TableView->itemAt(i, 0); //first column item
    QTableWidgetItem *item2 = TableView->itemAt(i, 1); //second column item
    // do desired stuff
  }
}
```

Note: I amn't aware of performance issues for this approach. You can check it.

Comment: This looks good. But I think it has to be `TableView->selectedRanges()`. This method itself seems to return a QList of QTableWidgetSelectionRange, not pointers to it. Next thing is I'm not really familiar with that Qt foreach thing, I'll have to look it up. One last thing: doesn't the column/row number start with 0? So `TableView->itemAt(i, 1);` would be second column item, wouldn't it?

Comment: @mattias: You are right everywhere. My apologies for a lot of misstyping) I have corrected the answer and replaced foreach with for.

Comment: @beduin: Thank you very much for your help. I replaced the inner iterator `i` by `j` just to make sure we don't have any problems. The strange thing is the return value of the `itemAt` method seem all to be the same and are pointing to my (row=0, col=0) cell. Edit: oops.. I think this is for coordinates..

Comment: @beduin: I replaced the pre-increments of i/j by post-increments. Furthermore I found out that if more than one row is selected it's not working anymore. Finally I found out top and bottom have to be switched in the for-statement (because: bottom >= top). I think I'll also add the leftColumn and rightColumn borders now.

Comment: @matthias: Bottom >= top - interesting feature.) Yeah, with columns you can do similiar things. Hope it will work in the end.)) Considering pre and post increment operators - it is recommended to use prefix form (you can read item 6 of [More Effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/More-Effective-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/020163371X)).

Comment: @matthias: Does it works finally? Or have you come up with another solution? I am curious in final solution.)

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm I wrote should do the trick:

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> selectedCells(TableView->selectedItems());

mCopyByteArray.clear();

QString text;
int row_count = TableView->rowCount();
int column_count = TableView->columnCount();

for( int i = 0; i < row_count; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < column_count; j++ )
    {
        text = selectedCells.at( i + j * row_count )->text();

        mCopyByteArray.append( text );
        mCopyByteArray.append( "\r\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified your solution to the following (see below, not familiar yet with the stackoverflow forum).
I think this is not the best one as we have to iterate through each

Comment: Ok, as I am a new user I cannot answer my own question... so no code details so far.

Comment: Strange thing... I think it worked before but now it throws me `QList<T>::at, "index out of range"` errors.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed a horrible mistake. My solution works only for all cells in a table. I'm sorry you can't use this solution ;(

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but some more information that I found out:

It seems that the order in which the selected items are returned by the `selectedItems()` function is the order in which they were selected.

Moreover, if the `selectionBehavior` property of the `QTableWidget` is set to `SelectRows`, then the selected items are returned in the order in which the rows were selected. For example, for a 2x3 table, where the rows are numbered 'A', 'B' and the columns are numbered '1', '2', '3': if you select B2 and then A1, then the selected items are returned as: B1,B2,B3,A1,A2,A3.